# Popup of QComboBox as QGraphicsProxyWidget obscured / intersected

Tags: qt, proxy, qgraphicsview, qcombobox

I have a *QGraphicsScene* in which I am displaying some *QGraphicsProxyWidgets*, for example a *QComboBox*. In the initial state, everything is fine:

[image: Initial State]

However, once the popup portion of the combobox is shown, it is not on top of the scene, but behind the elements following south of the combobox:

[image: Popup State]

I am already giving the proxy a high Z level value whenever the combobox is hovered, but that doesn't help.

```
bool MyClass::sceneEventFilter(QGraphicsItem* pWatchedObj, QEvent* pEvent)
{
    if(pEvent->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneHoverEnter)
    {
        if(pWatchedObj == m_pProxy)
        {
            m_pProxy->setZValue(zValue() + 200);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea? Do I have to somehow intercept the mouse press events and recalculate the comboxo size (plus its popup) to notify the scene/view for a proper re-ordering/sorting in terms of Z levels?

Comment: Try to do setZValue for the proxy widget immediately after it is created by scene->addWidget(). Assuming set Z-order always able to raise the window is maybe not right.

Comment: you need give more information what is parent child relation of all items involved in this problem. The `zValue` have impact only on direct siblings all other `QGraphicItem` are ordered by child parent relation (and some flag which allows to draw child behind parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** z-values only count between sibling elements.

---

I eventually found the issue and its solution:

The widget proxies as shown in the screenshot for the *QComboBox* and the *QLineEdit* are parented to different *QGraphicsItems* (in my case one QLabel and one input widget are always grouped toghether to one *QGraphicsItem*).

I assumed that the z-values that I set will have a global effect = highest value will be the top object in the whole scene irrespective of hierarchies. That however is not the case. By setting a high z-value for the *QComboBox* I only ensured that it will be drawn above the sibling *QLabel*.

The correct apporach however was (in my scenario) to increase the z-value of the *QGraphicsItem* that the *QLabel* and the *QComboBox* are parented to. That way its children are also "higher" and so can overdraw the next *QLabel* and *QLineEdit* (since the belong to a now "lower" different *QGraphicsItem*).

Answer (score 0):

QWidget has raise() method for raising the widget to the top of the parent widget's stack.

Get QGraphicsProxyWidget's widget with the widget() method and then use the raise() method.

Function would be:

```
bool MyClass::sceneEventFilter(QGraphicsItem* pWatchedObj, QEvent* pEvent)
{
    if(pEvent->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneHoverEnter)
    {
        if(pWatchedObj == m_pProxy)
        {
            m_pProxy->widget()->raise();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Try the above change. It should work out well.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work. The dropdown box is still occluded. Perhaps, I need a way to call raise() on the dropdown selection box itself, instead of on the input/display field.

Comment: Have you added the addWidget() method before because widget() returns embedded widget from addWidget().

Comment: Yes. The whole scene is constructed before the sceneEventFilter() ever gets active. Otherwise, retrieving the widget would return a null pointer and the call to raise() would cause an exception.

Comment: Both raise() and setZValue() methods don't work,I think the problem lies somewhere else and not in the above function.

Comment: Could be, although I have no real idea yet where this could be. I will try to create a minimal example with just a scene, a rectangular shape and the dropdown. Perhaps that narrows it down.